# Renormalisation of asymptotically free theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In the end of 27 in Srednicki book in QFT https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-field-theory/718DD037728FB3745F48A40A6D9A8A1C, when he is discussing the case of asymptotically free theory, he gives an expression for the $\beta$-function of $\phi^3$ theory in $D = 6$ dimensions.
$$
\alpha (\mu_2) = \frac{\alpha (\mu_1)}{1 + \frac{3}{2} \alpha (\mu_1) \ln (\mu_2 / \mu_1)}
$$

$\alpha(\mu)$ increases, with the decrease of $\mu$.
Then there is a following claim:

> If the particle mass is nonzero, this process stops at $\mu \sim m$. This is because the minimum value of $s$ is $4m^2$, and so the factor $\ln (s / \mu^2)$ becomes an unwanted large log for $\mu \ll m$. We should therefore not use values of $\mu$ below $m$.

How to correctly interpret this quote? Does this mean, that if one wants to investigate the theory at scales below $m$, the parameters and coupling constants of the theory would be fixed and approximately equal to their values at energy $\sim m$? It is clear, that integrating out further degrees of freedom is not possible, because as $m$ is the lightest scale in the theory one encounters `theory with nothing`. The minimum values of $s = 4m^2$ corresponds to the minimal energy of $2$-particle state, but what does this mean in this context?

i would be grateful for clarification and commenting on this statement!